# Shows White Screen After Splash screen iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, node-modules

I am developing an app in react native, I made launch screen for splash and the issue is after splash it loads module. So, for 2-4 seconds the blank screen appears. Below is the code of Appdelegate.m

```
[RNSplashScreen show];

jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"prescrip"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
rootViewController.view = rootView;
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Kindly help me in this situation

Comment: what about Android , is working fine in android

Comment: Yes, its working fine in android. Also I made it working iOS as well

Comment: can you share how did it?